# Format used for date in Highcharts - Line with markers chart type

Tags: highcharts, date-conversion

What kind of format has the date been converted to in
https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/line-markers?

I am generating data but I need to convert the data into this format, `strtotime` doesn't seem to do the trick.

[image]

Comment: You just need to multiply by 1000 the php timestamp to have a javascript timestamp

Comment: @Core972 you are right, you can write it as answer, I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to multiply by 1000 the PHP timestamp to have a javascript timestamp

```
var jsTimestamp = 1545055048 * 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x):

> For datetime axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since
>   1970.

`datetime` axes data format:

```
[
   x value, - timestamp in milliseconds since 1970
   y value
]
```